# Xamarin Forms - Salesforce - TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2. error for POST API call for Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

We are trying to call Salesforce restful APIs from our Xamarin Forms project. These calls works fine in terms of iOS application but failed for Android.

```
HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient();
message = await authClient.PostAsync("url", content); 
string responseString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

We receive below response in "responseString" variable for Android.

```
<tr><td width="100%" height="100%"><div class="content">
<h1>**Stronger security is required**</h1><div class="simple">
<p>**To access this website, update your web browser or upgrade your operating system to support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.**</p>
<p>For more information, see 
<a href="https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221207&amp;language=en_US" target="_blank">Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0</a>.
</p>
</div></div></td></tr>
</table></body>
</html>
```

We need to find a solution which should support iOS, Android and Win 10 application. WE checked for iOS and it worked. Now chekcing for Android and not working. For Windows we sis not check.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not personally run into this issue but you might give [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) a shot. Installing that library allows you to pass a `NativeMessageHandler` into your `HttpClient`. This will use the native implementations on Android, which will allow extra security features that do not come out of the box using the Xamarin Forms implementation.

You should also update the Xamarin Forms library to the latest if possible.

You code would become (I also added a `using` as it is good practice):

```
using(HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler())) {
    message = await authClient.PostAsync("url", content); 
    string responseString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```